# Using ROS java on android for robot control

Tags: ros, robot, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm brand new to ROS so bear with me:
I was hoping for some advise as to how to approach a project I am attempting.  I have logic control written in Java (as an Android application) that I want to implement on a Dr. Robot Jaguar 4x4 robot (compatible with ROS Fuerte).  My plan was to create a simple Android app that could just act as a passthrough converting java commands into ROS instructions, however as far as I can tell, Ros Java was designed to use Catkin and I can't figure out how to build the Jaguar drivers with Catkin.  I really appreciate any suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192511/using-ros-java-on-android-for-robot-control/) by [navy_robots](https://answers.ros.org/users/20179/navy_robots/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should also target at least ROS Hydro, since that is where rosjava/android really matured and became useable.

You can use a [rosbuild workspace together with a catkin workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_rosbuild_with_catkin), or you can [catkinize](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild) the provided Dr. Robot package by rewriting the manifest.xml->package.xml and updating CMakeLists.txt.

There may also be some dependency issues with migrating the code from fuerte to hydro, but from secondhand experience it's not bad, just stick to the migration [guides](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration).

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1